# CRM 2013 Updating the Quote Product section

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Has anyone tried to create a plugin that updates the record's values in the Quote Product form? I created one, because I need a custom formula that calculates the Extended Amount field, but there are automatic calculations in the CRM that fill these fields. This doesn't allow me to update the formula of calculation at all.

What my plugin do, is:

1. Gets the values from the fields Price per unit, Quantity and Discount % (which is a custom field);
2. Calculates the value that I need;
3. Sets it at the extended amount field.

But, none of this works because I get a "Business Process Error"; 
Basically this error tells me that I can't use the record's guid to access it.

Here is my code:

```
protected void ExecutePostQuoteProductUpdate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        if (localContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }

        IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
        IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

        Guid quoteProductID = (Guid)((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Id;
        ColumnSet set = new ColumnSet();
        set.AllColumns = true;

        var quote = service.Retrieve("quotedetail", quoteProductID, set);
        var priceperunit = quote.Attributes["priceperunit"];
        var teamleader = quote.Attributes["new_disc"];
        var manualdiscountamount = quote.Attributes["manualdiscountamount"];
        var volumediscountamount = quote.Attributes["volumediscountamount"];
        var VAT = (int)quote.Attributes["new_vat"];

        var discountamount = (double)priceperunit * (double)teamleader / 100;
        var baseamount = (double)priceperunit - discountamount;
        var tax = baseamount * VAT / 100;
        var extendedamount = baseamount + tax;
        quote.Attributes["new_discountamount"] = discountamount;
        quote.Attributes["baseamount"] = baseamount;
        quote.Attributes["tax"] = tax;
        quote["description"] = priceperunit;
        quote.Attributes["extendedamount"] = extendedamount;
        service.Update(quote);


    }
```

Please, tell me if there is a way to access those fields and use/set them.

Thanks in Advance!
:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update `extendedamount` directly - instead if you use the built-in fields which automatically calculate it then CRM will take care of this for you.

Those fields are: `baseamount`, `quantity`, `discountamount`, and `tax`. These are `Money` fields so you will need to store them as such:

```
quote.Attributes["baseamount"] = new Money(baseamount); // Money and decimal numbers use the "decimal" datatype and not double.
```

As for your custom calculation, you just need to convert the percentage stored in your custom field into the actual amount and assign it to the `discountamount` attribute. Something like:

```
var discountamount = (decimal)priceperunit * (decimal)teamleader / 100;
// Assigning the actual discount amount will automatically recalculate the extended amount on the line.
// No need to recalculate all fields. 
quote.Attributes["discountamount"] = new Money(discountamount);
```

Note that `tax` may need to be recalculated to reflect the discount, but the process should work exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you, Jason! I now know that I have to use the other fields in  order to set the Extended Amount to a certain value. 

Can you please tell me how do I access the fields like priceperunit, because this way 

var priceperunit = quote.Attributes["priceperunit"];

is giving me an ISV Error in the CRM :/

Comment: The "priceperunit" attribute would only be brought in if it were updated by the GUI (or more specifically, the delta change), otherwise you would need to bring it in as part of an image. If you know `baseamount` and `quantity` then you could simply do `price = baseamount / quantity`

Comment: That's a good workaround, but unfortunately I don't have access to the **baseamount** either.

Comment: The same goes with `baseamount` - It will not be available under `quote.Attributes` unless it was updated by process initiating the change. It, however, is always available using images. Here is a sample on how to use images: http://sumedha8.blogspot.com/2012/10/sample-plug-in-compare-pre-and-post.html

Comment: Thanks a million Jason Faulkner! I will look into this.